# Update Leaflet circleMarker position with Android GPS

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gps, android

An Android code sends the latitude and longitude coords to a (html)Leaflet map (stored in Android Asset folder), which add a circleMarker to the actual poisiton.

```
function updateLocation(lat,lng,time){

map.panTo(new L.LatLng(lat,lng));

var circle = L.circleMarker([lat, lng], 10, {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map);
```

I want to update the position, not to add to map again and again, when the GPS sends new positions. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
if (marker) {
map.removeLayer(marker);
}
marker = new L.circleMarker([lat, lng]).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to give some explanation as to how and where to use your code, and what it does.  This then helps any users in the future that may have the same issue understand how to use your solution.